# Rails - Setting up a helper to display user by gender

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have my user gender stored as a string male/female (as this is how it is retrieved from Facebook API)

The goal is to render a partial showing users by gender depending on the gender of the logged in user, but I'm having a little trouble setting up a helper

```
def male 
  @male = @user.gender.male
end
```

then my view..

```
<% @users.male.each do |male| %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= male.firstname %></li>
        <li><%= male.age %></li>
        <li><%= male.location %></li>
    </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong, been stuck on this for ages :(

Comment: Hang on you want to render a partial depending on the gender. Could you not just a `if` statement that could check what gender the user is. Then dependent on what gender they are would deter what partial is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scopes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :male, -> { where gender: 'male' }
  scope :female, -> { where gender: 'female' }
end
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @males = @users.male # or use User.male, but @users might already be filtered
  @females = @users.female
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= @males.each do |user| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: this gives me undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on @males.each do

Comment: Did you try both `@users.male` and `User.male`? If both fail, perhaps the identifier for male/female is different in your case.

Comment: Got it to work by moving the controller code into show. Guess I should have figured that out earlier. I did have to use User.male. Thanks so much, scopes is perfect for handling this.